# Gtk screenshot program weirdness (python)

Tags: python, gtk

I found some python code online for taking continuous screenshots with Gtk but I have a major problem. When I run my code:

```
import cv2
import Image
import numpy as np


def getScreenByGtk():
    import gtk.gdk      

    w = gtk.gdk.get_default_root_window()

    sz = w.get_size()

    pb = gtk.gdk.Pixbuf(gtk.gdk.COLORSPACE_RGB,False,8,sz[0],sz[1])

    pb = pb.get_from_drawable(w,w.get_colormap(),0,0,0,0,sz[0],sz[1])

    if (pb == None):
        return False
    else:
        width,height = pb.get_width(),pb.get_height()
        return Image.fromstring("RGB",(width,height),pb.get_pixels() )

cv2.namedWindow('image', cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)

while True:
    screen_img = getScreenByGtk()
    screen_img_array = np.asarray(screen_img)
    cv2.imshow('image',screen_img_array)
    cv2.waitKey(1)

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

It gives me images that are slanted to the left:

[image]

I've been trying to find a solution online for this but I can't.

I'm running lubuntu 12.04 in virtual box

Comment: This issue happens in Windows as well, this happens in Windows when the width is not divisible by 4.So you have padding and that's what's slanting it. Were you able to figure that out?

Comment: This explains the padding issue which I'm sure is causing this slant: https://developer.gnome.org/gdk-pixbuf/stable/gdk-pixbuf-The-GdkPixbuf-Structure.html#image-data

Comment: Did any of you guys find a solution to this?